# Getting HTTP Basic: Access denied error using Recurly in Django

Tags: django, recurly

I am trying to access my Recurly plans in django 1.5 like this:

```
import recurly
plan_list = recurly.Plan.all()
```

I get the error:

> HTTP Basic: Access denied.

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs when you do not have the correct recurly API key.  I switched to a valid key and all worked like a charm.